# HTML data is returned as response instead of string

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am doing simple client request to check whether my server is working proper in my Android device or not. Below is my code. I am using `HttpClient` since it is a PCL project using Xamarin framework.

Android:

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(App.BaseUrl);

var response = client.PostAsync(App.TestApi, new StringContent("")).Result;

                if (response != null)
                {
                    var responseString = response.Content;
                    string responseBody = responseString.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                }
```

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("testapi/test")]      
        public HttpResponseMessage TestApi()
        {
            Log.WriteLog("testapi/test");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
        }
```

I am not posting any data. First I tried Get request in both server and client I got same HTML response, then I changed to POST, still same HTML response is coming instead of "Success"

**When I try same request from RestClient, its returning "Success" as response**. But in mobile instead of returning "Success" message, HTML string is returned as response. I have done many request like this, but this particular is behaving like this. This may be very simple, but I don't know how to search on this.

Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE SPINNER -->

        <!-- BEGIN ACTUAL CONTENT -->

<!-- END ACTUAL CONTENT -->

<script>

</script>




    </div>
    <!-- END QUICK SIDEBAR -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <script></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <script></script>

    <script></script>
    <script>

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

One more thing what I have found is `I have two servers, in one server I am getting "Success" response in device properly. But from another server I am not getting. Is it something to do with server setup`?

Comment: what HTML string response you got from your mobile ?

Comment: @ Frebin Francis Updated response...